# Prevent mongoose from inserting template Schema in db

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am creating a demo gaming web app with express and mongoose. There are several game types such as `quizzes` and `puzzles`.

I am trying to create one main Schema `Games`, which gets inherited from other Schema game types. For example, something like this:

```
const quizzes = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: { type: String },
    answer: { type: String }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('quiz', quizzes);


const Games = new mongoose.Schema({
    // these fields apply to all games
    game_name: String,
    date_created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

    // game type
    game_type: { type: String, enum: ['quizzes', 'puzzles', 'multiplayer'] },
    game_content: { type: Object, enum: [quizzes, puzzles] }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('games', Games);
```

I am effectively using quizzes as a template to be added to `game_content` and stored in the db as a game. However, when I try to create a new game by doing:

```
const quiz = new Quiz({
        question: "this is question 1", 
        answer: "this is answer 1"
    }) 
    const game = new Game({
        game_name: "game 1", 
        game_type: "quizzes", 
        game_content: quiz
    })
    await game.save();
```

It thinks `quizzes` is a real model and I get an empty quizzes table in my db along with my games table. How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have quizzes in the database, don't create a schema for it. You can define the schema for the game content with just a nested object. Same with creating the documents.